# Disable manual entry in date input field

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

I have an input type date like:

```
<input type="date" />
```

I don't want users to be able to change the date manually, but require them to use the button provided for.
So I did:

```
<input type="date" onkeydown="return false"/>
```

No problem with Chrome but it doesn't work with Firefox.

Comment: Please don't do this. You will be breaking accessibility, and also you will frustrate your users.

Comment: Hide the input.  Then users can't type into it.

Comment: @freedomn-m does the date overlay still show?

Comment: Depends entirely on what the "*button provided for*" does.   Stick a `<span>` next to the button to "show" the selection.   If it's using the browser date picker, then this isn't a viable option (as the picker is part of the input), but if there's a separated provided button, then yes as it would be provided by the additional functionality.

Comment: "button provided for" = the browser date picker
I need to have a date min value and date maxvalue

Answer (score 0):

you can just add `readonly` attribute:

```
<input type="date" readonly />
```

Comment: `readonly` does not allow the user to select a date

Comment: On Chrome, `onkeydown="return false"`, works good, but not on Firefox while `onkeydown` is compatible with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, now i understand what do you want.
you're right onkeydown="return false" does not work on firefox because firefox does not care about the return of this function unlike other browsers (neither onkeyup).

you can acheive what you want by prevent the user from focusing the input, like this:

```
<input type="date" onclick="this.blur();" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: Cool, let's see how many ways accessibility can be broken…